# Have I implemented deltatime correctly?

Tags: java, time

I am making a game in Java and wanted to implement a deltatime system. However I am not sure if I have implemented it correctly. Is the way I have done it correct, or should I change it.

My code looks like this:

```java
long oldtime = System.nanoTime();

while (true) {
    long newtime = System.nanoTime();
    long deltatime = (newtime - oldtime) / 1000000;
    System.out.println(deltatime);
    oldtime = newtime;

    // render code

    try {
        Thread.sleep(Math.max(0, 32 - deltatime));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the result of our own test meet your expactation?

Comment: I think an important part of delta time is what you actually do in `// render code` (i.e. how you take into account the actual amount of time that has passed). You've not shown us that part.

Comment: Have you tryed to use LigGdx to create your game. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to measure how long the rendering took. Therefore, I suggest a cleaner approach by storing the starting time in a variable (`start`) and then calculating the difference to the current time after the rendering took place. This would allow you to measure sub-steps easily by just adding another comparison to the current time in between.

Always be careful with the units (ms, µs, ms) and make it obvious by naming the variable accordingly (e.g. `deltaMs`) or by using a comment. It's also a good idea to protect the reference by declaring it `final`.

*Here is a simple example:*

```java
while (true) {
    final long start = System.nanoTime(); // initial reference

    // simulate render code
    try { Thread.sleep(32); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    final long deltaMs = (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1_000_000;
    System.out.println("Render took " + deltaMs + "ms");
}
```

*Here is a nested example:*

```java
while (true) {
    final long start = System.nanoTime();
    /* A */ try { Thread.sleep(20); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    final long deltaMsPartA = (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1_000_000;
    System.out.println("Render part A took " + deltaMsPartA + "ms");

    final long startPartB = System.nanoTime();
    /* B */ try { Thread.sleep(30); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    final long deltaMsPartB = (System.nanoTime() - startPartB) / 1_000_000;
    System.out.println("Render part B took " + deltaMsPartB + "ms");

    final long deltaMs = (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1_000_000;
    System.out.println("Overall render took " + deltaMs + "ms");
}
```